Crash on - [ FBSSceneParameters initWithXPCDictionary: ] with iOS 18 +
got a crash recently after iOS 18 release, here is the stacktrace, since it didn't provide the code location, so hard to reproduce, so wonder if anyone has similar issues, or any ideas this issue can be from? and it usually it crash in Thread 6 or Thread 13, and not crash at the time when app first launch, and seems happened in general across the whole app.
0
FrontBoardServices
- [ FBSSceneParameters initWithXPCDictionary: ] + 497
1 BaseBoard
_BSXPCDecodeObjectFromContext + 2300
2
BaseBoard _BSXPCDecodeObjectForKey + 220
3
BoardServices
+ [ BSXPCServiceConnectionProxy decodeArguments:outArgs:fromMessage:forConnection: ] + 852
4
BoardServices
+ [ BSXPCServiceConnectionProxy invokeMethod:onTarget:withMessage:forConnection:completion: ] + 264
5
BoardServices
[ BSXPCServiceConnectionEventHandler connection:handleMessage: ] + 1156
6
BoardServices
BSXPCServiceConnectionExecuteCallOut + 240
7
BoardServices
- [ BSXPCServiceConnectionEventHandler connection:handleMessage: ] + 176
8
BoardServices
- [ BSXPCServiceConnection _connection_handleMessage:fromPeer:withHandoff: ] +524
9
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
10
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_client_callout + 20
11
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 744
12
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_lane_invoke + 432
13
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 368
14
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_lane_invoke + 432
15
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288
16
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 540
17
libsystem_pthread.dylib
_pthread_wqthread + 288
18
libsystem_pthread.dylib
start_wqthread + 8

